# Is it possible to use expo video in bare react native project?

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to use expo video in bare react native project if install expo module according to new unimodules of expo?

Comment: Expo uses `react-native-video` so you would just use tha

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a video in your React Native App with expo, you can use Video expo

```
import { Video } from 'expo';
```

because react-native-video has conflict with expo, if you will use expo and you can't use `resizeMode` you need to update expo and create a new proyect, because, the expo librarys can be broken, if you will create a new proyec, you can move the screens of the old proyect to the new proyect